# Programmatically generate nested for loops

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, closures

The underscore mixin and the function below do the exact same thing in two different ways, they get all the pairs for an array. I was wondering how I can create a function (closure?) that allows me to pass in how many "pairs" or groupings of array items I want instead of nesting `for loops` or `range-maps` every time.

```
getPairs: function(arr){
  return _.chain(_.range(arr.length))
  .map(function(setOne){
    return _.chain(_.range(arr.length))
    .map(function(setTwo){
      return [
        arr[setOne],
        arr[setTwo],
      ]
    })
    .value()
  })
  .value()
}

function getPairs(arr){
  var pairs = []
  for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    for(var p = 0; p < arr.length; p++){
      var pair = [
        arr[i],
        arr[p],
      ]
      pairs.push()
    }
  }
  return pairs
}
```

Comment: Weird. I was about to ask an extremely related question, and this one was on top of the list, having been asked a minute earlier.

Comment: I don't find that in underscore code, an the function under is missing a `.push()` I suppose. Can you add a example of the input and output you want to get?

Comment: What do you mean by "how many pairs" ? Do you mean limiting the size of the resulting array?

Comment: yes @analytalica the size of the resulting array AKA how many nested for loops there are.

Comment: You cannot get pairs of elements without having exactly two for loops. You have to iterate through the array twice to find pairs. If all you want to do is reduce the size of the resulting array, you can do that with array.slice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: @analytalica Lets say I wanted to get the `quadruplet` or any groupings of several I need to hard-code a multitude of nested loops ? What If I wanted a grouping of 100?

Comment: Ah. The word "pair" threw me off, because "pair" suggests exactly two items.

Comment: I don't find that `getPairs` in underscore code, an the function `getPairs ` (under) is missing a `pairs.push()` I suppose. Can you add a example of the input and output you want to get?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fascinating question.  To get a simple solution I had to think a bit outside the box.  As it is, the whole thing can be accomplished with two `for` loops and some heavy math.  Here's the code:

```
function getGroupings(arr, numPerGroup){
    numPerGroup > 1 || (numPerGroup = 2);
    var groups = Math.pow(arr.length, numPerGroup);
    var groupings = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < numPerGroup; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < groups; j++) {
            groupings[j] || groupings.push(Array(numPerGroup));
            var index = Math.floor(j / Math.pow(arr.length, i)) % arr.length;
            groupings[j][i] = arr[index];
            if (i === numPerGroup - 1) groupings[j] = groupings[j].reverse();
        }
    }
    return groupings;
}
```

A few notes on how this works:

- It runs the outer `for` loop once for every item in the inner arrays, and the inner `for` loop once for every item in the outer array.  Backwards, you might say.
- The inner `for` loop works kind of like a binary clock where (value-of-clock) === (index of the passed-in array we want to access).
- Where *n* = (length of the passed-in array), it will increment the clock every time in the one's place, one (*n* ^ 1)th as often in the (*n* ^ 1)'s place, one (*n* ^ 2)th as often in the (*n* ^ 2)'s place, and so on until the (*n* ^ num-per-group)'s place.
- On the last iteration, it reverses all the inner arrays to actually put the one's place last, the (*n* ^ 1)'s place second-to-last, etc... Not necessarily necessary, but produces a more expected output.

Example:

Say you have an array, `var arr = [3, 6, 9]`, and you want to get all possible groupings of 3--`getGroupings(arr, 3);`.  The actual number of groups is `arr.length ^ 3 = 27`, so the function will generate an array of 27 arrays.

(Ignoring the outer `for` loop--imagine all its iterations happen at once) The binary clock starts at 0s, so the first grouping is `arr[0], arr[0], arr[0]`--`[3, 3, 3]`.

On the next iteration, the 1's place advances by one--`arr[0], arr[0], arr[1]`--`[3, 3, 6]`, then `[3, 3, 9]`.

Next it's time for the 3's place to advance and the one's place to reset--`arr[0], arr[1], arr[0]`, so grouping 4 is `[3, 6, 3]`.  And so on until the 27th array, `[9, 9, 9]`.

Here's a [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/bowheart/a7puwo5k/).  Try it out!

Answer (score 0):

Since this question is more about the implementation of the algorithm I use Swift to implement it:

```
// provide 2 parameters, an array and the size of one group of elements
// [[T]] means an array of an array of type T (placeholder for anything)
func getPair<T>(array: [T], pairCount: Int) -> [[T]] {
    if pairCount <= 1 {
        // puts each element of array in a separate array:
        // [3, 6, 7] -> [[3], [6], [7]]
        return array.map{ [$0] }
    }
    // returns a flattened array of all possible element combinations
    // flatMap: array gets mapped to all other possible combinations of one less than pairCount and gets flattened/concatenated
    // el1: element of the array which can be used in the closure
    return array.flatMap{ el1 in
        // smaller pairs are mapped to bigger ones
        // el2: element of the smaller pairs (one small pair) which can be used in the closure
        return getPair(array, pairCount - 1).map{ el2 in
            return [el1] + el2
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see this recursive function is very efficient in terms of code lines, but in comparison to the more C like version below it is 2-22 (average: 4-6) times slower especially for a big pairCounts.

Here is the other version:

```
// helper function which "creates" for loops and passes the indexes to a closure which takes an array of indexes
// indexes = [2, 3, 4] ==> for 4 times { for 3 times { for 2 times {} } }
// the corresponding passed indexes range from [0, 0, 0] to [2 - 1, 3 - 1, 4 - 1] so you can pass array.count directly
// therefore the index of the inner for loop can be accessed with passedArray[0] and so on
func forIndexes(indexes: [Int], closure: [Int] -> ()) {
    if indexes.count == 0 { return }

    // array which gets passed to the closure and modified over time
    var currentIndexes = Array(count: indexes.count, repeatedValue: 0)

    // maximum overall count of inner for loop: [2, 4, 5] => 2*4*5 = 40
    var count = 1
    for var i = 0; i < indexes.count; i++ {
        count *= indexes[i]
    }

    for var i = 0; i < count; i++ {
        // call closure with currentIndexes
        closure(currentIndexes)

        // increment first current index and check whether the other ones have to be updated
        if ++currentIndexes[0] == indexes[0] {
            // condition: j < indexes.count - 1 => prevent out of bounds exception for: currentIndexes[j+1]++
            for var j = 0; j < indexes.count - 1; j++ {
                if currentIndexes[j] >= indexes[j] {
                    currentIndexes[j] -= indexes[j]
                    currentIndexes[j+1]++
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

func getPair2<T>(array: [T], pairCount: Int) -> [[T]] {
    var result = [[T]]()
    // pair count determines the depth of the nested for loops while array.count specifies the loop count
    forIndexes(Array(count: pairCount, repeatedValue: array.count), closure: { indexes in
        // map array elements from all possible indexes
        result.append(indexes.map{ index in
            return array[index]
        })
    })
    return result
}
```