# Conditionally use parts of a nested for loop

Tags: python-3.x, loops, for-loop, filter, list-comprehension

I've searched for this answer extensively, but can't seem to find an answer.  Therefore, for the first time, I am posting a question here.

I have a function that uses many parameters to perform a calculation.  Based on user input, I want to iterate through possible values for some (or all) of the parameters.  If I wanted to iterate through all of the parameters, I might do something like this:

```
for i in range(low1,high1):
    for j in range(low2,high2):
        for k in range(low3,high3):
            for m in range(low4,high4):
                doFunction(i, j, k, m)
```

If I only wanted to iterate the 1st and 4th parameter, I might do this:

```
for i in range(low1,high1):
    for m in range(low4,high4):
        doFunction(i, user_input_j, user_input_k, m)
```

My actual code has almost 15 nested for-loops with 15 different parameters - each of which could be iterable (or not).  So, it isn't scalable for me to use what I have and code a unique block of for-loops for each combination of a parameter being iterable or not.  If I did that, I'd have 2^15 different blocks of code.

I could do something like this:

```
if use_static_j == True:
    low2  = -999
    high2 = -1000
for i in range(low1,high1):
    for j in range(low2,high2):
        for k in range(low3,high3):
            for m in range(low4,high4):
                j1 = j if use_static_j==False else user_input_j
                doFunction(i, j1, k, m)
```

I'd just like to know if there is a better way.  Perhaps using filter(), map(), or list comprehension...  (which I don't have a clear enough understanding of yet)

Comment: Sadly, im not really able to help you, however I want to share an approach I have used in the past. If you have to conditionally use loops, you can try to build a structure that only uses a single loop by mapping the options to their index in the cartesian array built from all options. so if you had option a in range 0 - 9 and option b in range 0 - 4 you'd iterate over 0-49 and set option a as iteration / 5 and option b to iteration % 5

Comment: I thought about doing something like that, but it got hard to think about with 15 different parameters.  Adding to that the ranges could be negative and that I actually might have additional input to specify the "steps" for the range.  For example, -90 to 90 degrees with a step size of .1...

Comment: `param = param_min + (index % (multiplied 'inner loop' param ranges)) * step_size`
with the param range being `(param_max - param_min) / stepsize`, no?

Comment: i found this question that seems to be going in the same direction https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31362507/programmatically-generate-nested-for-loops
additionally, this could be a problem best solved by recursion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, you could build an array of the parameters and then call the function with each of the values in the array. The easiest way to build the array is using recursion over a list defining the ranges for each parameter. In this code I've assumed a list of tuples consisting of `start`, `stop` and `scale` parameters (so for example the third element in the list produces `[3, 2.8, 2.6, 2.4, 2.2]`). To use a static value you would use a tuple `(static, static+1, 1)`.

```
def build_param_array(ranges):
    r = ranges[0]
    if len(ranges) == 1:
        return [[p * r[2]] for p in range(r[0], r[1], -1 if r[1] < r[0] else 1)]
    res = []
    for p in range(r[0], r[1], -1 if r[1] < r[0] else 1):
        pa = build_param_array(ranges[1:])
        for a in pa:
            res.append([p * r[2]] + a)
    return res

# range = (start, stop, scale)
ranges = [(1, 5, 1),
          (0, 10, .1),
          (15, 10, .2)
          ]

params = build_param_array(ranges)

for p in params:
    doFunction(*p)
```

Comment: This did work.  But now I've got a new issue.  Using this method, if I enable all options, the program terminates with an Memory Error.  I'll treat this issue as something separate as your answer did work if I don't enable all options.

Comment: @DavidSteele yeah, that is the problem here that you can end up generating a pretty big array if you have a large number of options. One way to work around that would be to nest a number of loops of this code, so for example split your sets of options into groups of 4 and build param arrays for each of them, then you only need 4 nested for loops to process 16 options.

Comment: Thanks again, Nick.  I'm experimenting with that now - along with other options like memmap and h5py.

Comment: Trying to understand ranges[1:]...  This is slicing?

Comment: @DavidSteele yes - `ranges[1:]` is basically all of the `ranges` list excluding the first element (`ranges[0]`)

Comment: @DavidSteele I built a small example of a 2-deep nested loop each of 2 parameters: https://rextester.com/NHBE30751

Comment: Thanks, Nick.  You are awesome!  I actually did something similar with  ```for i, j in product(params1, params2)```

Comment: @DavidSteele that's also a good way to do it, probably better in fact.

Comment: FWIW, ```return [[p * r[2]] for p in range(r[0], r[1], -1 if r[1] < r[0] else 1)]``` doesn't work for all combinations.  For example, [-25, -24, .5]

Comment: @DavidSteele what values are you trying to get out of that tuple?

Comment: If I use ```ranges  = [(-7, -6, .5), (36, 37, .5)]```   The result is -3.5, 18.0